# SSH.NET: Is it possible to upload files using SFTP and preserve the file dates from source files?

Tags: c#, file-upload, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

Currently, I am using the Renci SSH.NET library to upload files to a Unix server using SFTP. One thing that I don't like is that after uploading files, the creation- and modified dates are altered to the time when the upload took place.

I would like to preserve the original file dates from the source files, is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SSH.NET library won't do it for you automatically. You have to code it.

There are `SftpClient.SetLastWriteTime` and `SftpClient.SetLastWriteTimeUtc` methods. But they are actually not implemented yet.

You can code it like this instead:

```
SftpFileAttributes fileAttributes = client.GetAttributes(targetFile);
fileAttributes.LastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(sourceFile);
client.SetAttributes(targetFile, fileAttributes);
```

Though due to a lack of UTC API in the `SftpFileAttributes`, you might have problems setting the timestamp correctly, if a client and a server are not in the same timezone.

---

For more details, see my answer to:
[Modified date time changes when moving a file from Windows to UNIX server using SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53063696/850848#53078702)

---

Or use another SFTP library capable for preserving the timestamp automatically, ideally with an UTC support.

For example, [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) does it automatically. Just use the [`Session.PutFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles):

```
session.PutFiles(sourceFile, targetFile).Check();
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*