# Modified date time changes when moving a file from Windows to UNIX server using SSH.NET

Tags: c#, linux, unix, sftp, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET in my C# application to copy files from a Windows to a UNIX server, I have a few scenarios for this:

1. In the UNIX server directory **if the file to be copied *does not exist***, then **the modified datetime of the file when it is copied to the UNIX server changes to the copied datetime**? Is this correct because the modified datetime is not supposed to change right?
2. In the UNIX Server directory **if the file to be copied *already exists***, then on copying the same file which gets replaced in the UNIX Server path **the modified datetime of the file does not change**!

I am confused with this modified datetime as I have read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638993/ssh-net-is-it-possible-to-upload-files-using-sftp-and-preserve-the-file-dates-f) that SSH.NET does it wrongly, is this supposed to be right?

For those of you asking to provide code, here goes:

```
private static int UploadFileToSFTP (string localFileFullPath, string uploadPath)
{
    try
    {
        Log.Debug("Inside Utilities.UploadFileToSFTP() with localFileFullPath=" + localFileFullPath + ", and remoteUploadPath=" + uploadPath);
        Log.Debug("Uploading File : " + uploadPath);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(localFileFullPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Log.Debug("Checking if path: " + Path.GetDirectoryName(uploadPath).Replace("\\", "/") + " already exists");
            if (!IsDirectoryExists(Path.GetDirectoryName(uploadPath).Replace("\\", "/")))
            {
                Log.Debug(Path.GetDirectoryName(uploadPath).Replace("\\", "/") + " | Directory does not exist, creating!");
                sftpClient.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(uploadPath).Replace("\\", "/"));
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Debug(Path.GetDirectoryName(uploadPath).Replace("\\", "/") + " | Directory already exists!");
            }
            Log.Debug("Checking if file: " + uploadPath + " already exists");
            if (sftpClient.Exists(uploadPath))
            {
                Log.Debug(uploadPath + " | File Already exists in the  Server");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Debug(uploadPath + " | File Does not exist in the  Server!");
            }
            sftpClient.BufferSize = 1024;
            sftpClient.UploadFile(fs, uploadPath);
            fs.Close();
        }

        return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Error("Error in Utilities.UploadFileToSFTP(): ", exception);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp of the file on the remote SFTP server will always be set to the the time the remote file was modified the last time (i.e. the upload time) – As with any other file on a Linux server.

As the [question you have linked yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36638993/850848) says:

> after uploading files, the creation- and modified dates are altered to the time when the upload took place.

---

I assume you somehow expect that the local file timestamp is involved. It's not. You are not uploading a local file. You are uploading data from a stream (`Stream` interface). SSH.NET (let alone SFTP server) does not even know that your instance of `Stream` originated from a local file. So SSH.NET (let alone the SFTP server) cannot know the local file timestamp.

In the end, it behaves like if you have copied a file on the Linux server via a pipe (similar to a stream) instead of using `cp` command, like:

```
cat source > target
```

The contents gets copied, but the timestamp will always be the time of the last modification (i.e. the copy time).

---

If you want the remote file timestamp to match timestamp of the source local file, you have to code that (like done in the question you know already):
[SSH.NET: Is it possible to upload files using SFTP and preserve the file dates from source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36638993/850848)

Note that it's not true that *"SSH.NET does it wrongly"*. It does what it should (could). It nowhere promises you to preserve the timestamp for you.

Comment: Thanks, wasn’t aware that a stream would be created for this!